# XMLReader load from url throwing exception in .NET Core 1.0 project

Tags: asp.net, xml, rss, asp.net-core, xmlreader

I need to load some xml data from an RSS feed. If I create a .NET Framework 4.5.2 Web API application, using `XMLReader.Create(url)` works just fine. However if I try to run the same code in a .NET Core 1.0 Web API application, it fails with the following error:

`Cannot open 'http://[RSS feed url]'. The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.`

This is the code, which I've run inside brand new, separate 4.5.2 and .NET Core 1.0 Web API applications:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://[RSS feed url]");
    // ...
}
```

I know the feed URL works, I've tried a couple different ones that I am able to otherwise load just fine. I've also tried using `XDocument.Load(url)` as well, and get the same exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Likely not implemented or a constrain, .NET Core is a completely separate   framework from .NET Framework 4.5.2 and is written from Scratch, so don't expect it to be feature complete with the full .NET Framework. Look at the source (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) and the exact exception where it happens and what is checked there.

Comment: @Tseng You're right.. looked at System.Xml.ReaderWriter.cs and the XmlReader Create methods throw null..